# Parse Pandas Dataframe in Order of List of Strings

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a log file that I'm converting to a pandas df. I need to find specific log lines from the df and calculate the time between these lines, hence divide the entire log into multiple phases.

Df example:

```
log_level  timestamp               message
INFO       2019-10-31 12:00        A
INFO       2019-10-31 12:02        b
INFO       2019-10-31 12:00        c
INFO       2019-10-31 12:04        d
INFO       2019-10-31 12:00        e
INFO       2019-10-31 12:06        f
INFO       2019-10-31 12:00        g
INFO       2019-10-31 12:08        h
INFO       2019-10-31 12:10        i
INFO       2019-10-31 12:12        j
INFO       2019-10-31 12:14        k
INFO       2019-10-31 12:16        l
INFO       2019-10-31 12:18        m
INFO       2019-10-31 12:18        n

msg_list = ['a', 'd','g','n', 'k']
```

Here, 'a' to 'd' becomes a phase, 'd' to 'g' another and so on until the end of the log. I have close to 40000 lines of log that I need to divide.

What is the best and most optimized way to do this since I have to parse close to 400 odd logs.

I am using str.contains to find the start and end indexes and get the time in between them, but I feel its not efficient enough, because it is looking at the Dataframe from top to bottom each time to find the strings.

Is it possible to look through the Dataframe only once, say if I find message 'a' then I look for the next message 'd' and next time look from 'd' to next message 'g', with some kinda positional index?

Some of my code:

```
@property
    def start_idx(self):
        if self._start_idx is None:
            self._start_idx = self.main_df.index[self.main_df['message'].str.contains(self.start_message)][0]
            print(self._start_idx)
        return self._start_idx

    @property
    def end_idx(self):
        if self._end_idx is None:
            self._end_idx = self.main_df.index[self.main_df['message'].str.contains(self.end_message)][0]
            print(self._end_idx)
        return self._end_idx

    @property
    def start_time(self):
        if self._start_time is None:
            self._start_time = self.phase_df.loc[self.start_idx, 'timestamp']
        return self._start_time

    @property
    def end_time(self):
        if self._end_time is None:
            self._end_time = self.phase_df.loc[self.end_idx, 'timestamp']
        return self._end_time

    @property
    def phase_df(self):
        if self._phase_df is None:
            self._phase_df = self.main_df.iloc[self.start_idx: self.end_idx]

        return self._phase_df

    @property
    def phase_time(self):
        if self._phase_time is None:
            self._phase_time = (self.end_time - self.start_time) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')

        return int(self._phase_time)
```

I have been calling this part of code multiple times for different start and end messages that I find.

Output Expected (in a separate df):

```
File    Phase1    Phase2    .... Phase N
Log1     120       120             120      (Time in seconds/minutes)
```

Comment: `df.groupby(df['message'].isin(msg_list).cumsum())['message','timestamp'].agg(message = ('message','first'),start=('timestamp','min'), end=('timestamp','max'))`

Comment: Thank you for replying, the code you pasted gives back the entire df. Sorry, I did not add the expected output before. I made edits now